# Scala passing a case class as a function

Tags: scala

which Scala magic allows MyClass to be passed as a function:

```
trait T
case class MyClass(x: String) extends T
def m(f: (String) => T): Unit = println("working")
m(MyClass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the case class, you're passing it's companion object, also called `MyClass`. `MyClass` (the companion) is a `Function1[String, T]` because the compiler automatically creates the method:

```
def apply(s: String): MyClass
```

You can check:

```
scala> MyClass.isInstanceOf[Function1[String, T]]
res53: Boolean = true
```